# Java: TextField Doesn't Convert to Integer Variable i

Tags: java, swing

I am doing work with text field i make a program in which user type i in text field it converts into int i but the problem is when user type i it doesn't convert into int i.The Condition does not work correctly why its happening.

```
public class A extends JFrame{

    private JTextField entervar;
    private JButton button;
    public A(){
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        entervar = new JTextField();
        entervar.setToolTipText("variable must be 'i'");

        entervar.setBounds(37,26,89,28);
        getContentPane().add(entervar);


        button = new JButton("Click");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String p = entervar.getText();

                try {
                    int i;
                    if ( p.equals("i") ) {
                        i = Integer.parseInt(p);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Enter Variable Must be i");

                }
            }

        });
        button.setBounds(108,121,89,28);
        getContentPane().add(button);
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new A();

    }
}
```

Comment: People may be more willing to help if you make your code more readable by indenting it properly (by putting more spaces in front of the appropriate lines – see the help for details.)

Comment: Do you mean to say when a user enters *i* it should be converted to 1 and when a user enters *ii* then it should be converted to 2?

Comment: @Blip  when user enter i then it convert into to int i variable

Comment: could you explain what you meant be *int i variable* in your previous comment? Your allow the user to enter `String` "i" and want it magically converted to `int`?

Comment: @Blip yes i really want this

Comment: and what value should *i* be converted to?

Comment: @Blip  user type "i" and that "i" converted into null int i

Comment: so why are you using `Integer.parseInt` you could write `i = null;` instead

Answer (score 1):

`p.equals("i")` means user enters "i" in the text field. SO it can't be converted to number "i" is not number.

Read about [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html). You can set NumberModel for int and get integer directly.